# Practical Aspects of Workshop Organization

Tags: etiquette, workshop

*I'm surprised I couldn't find any similar question. Please mark as duplicate if you know one.*

## What are the practical aspects one should not overlook when organizing a (small) workshop?

Organizing a small (~ less than 50 participants, on one day) workshop includes taking care of a lot of small details that I feel are easy to forget, and yet crucial (easy Wifi access, parking spots, break room, collecting information during registration, etc.)

What is your "to-do" list when you're in charge of organizing a gathering of that kind? What are the nice finishing touches (having work room available, creating a web forum for the attendees, etc.)?